# jQuery - Datatables, one full width row followed by 5 column row

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatables

I have a DataTable as follows:-

https://jsfiddle.net/7magtdyy/1/

```
<div id="tabs-<?php echo $cat_inc; ?>"> 

    <table class="table-products display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="hidden">id</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Short Title</th>
                <th class="hidden">Description</th>
                <th class="hidden">Cost</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Total Cost</th>
                <th>Options</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th class="hidden">id</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Short Title</th>
                <th class="hidden">Description</th>
                <th class="hidden">Cost</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Total Cost</th>
                <th>Options</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>                        

            <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 

                setup_postdata( $post );

                ?>

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="hidden"><?php the_ID(); ?></td>
                        <td><span class="product-image" style="background:url(<?php the_field('image'); ?>);"></span></td>
                        <td><?php the_field('short_title'); ?></td>
                        <td class="hidden"><?php the_field('description'); ?></td>
                        <td class="hidden"><?php the_field('cost_price'); ?></td>
                        <td><input class="product-quantity q<?php the_ID(); ?>" type="text" /></td>
                        <td><input class="product-total-cost c<?php the_ID(); ?>" type="text" /></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="add-row" name="add-row" value="Add"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

            <?php $product_increment++; endforeach; ?>

    </table>
```

Is there a way of displaying each row as a full width row, followed by a row of four columns, i.e:-

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><?php the_field('short_title'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="hidden"><?php the_ID(); ?></td>
        <td><span class="product-image" style="background:url(<?php the_field('image'); ?>);"></span></td>
        <td><?php the_field('short_title'); ?></td>
        <td class="hidden"><?php the_field('description'); ?></td>
        <td class="hidden"><?php the_field('cost_price'); ?></td>
        <td><input class="product-quantity q<?php the_ID(); ?>" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input class="product-total-cost c<?php the_ID(); ?>" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="add-row" name="add-row" value="Add"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image]

I've tried to do this but it's breaking the table, is there a function to define the columns? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

since you are creating a table using php and then initializing a Datatable, rather than using serverside processing you must be able to do it like this.

```
 <tr>
  <td colspan="5">Full Width Row</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You would think so but this causes an error with DataTables; 
see; https://jsfiddle.net/7magtdyy/2/ - "Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined"